# query execution time mysql: workbench vs through php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a query which is executed in Workbench in 2 sec. When I execute it in PHP file it takes about 40 sec.! Any ideas why?

thnks.
Query:

```
SELECT
        sum((1 - (Data.Data1.`Ggdata` / 100)) * (Data.Data1.`Datagg`)) As 'EUH'
    FROM
        Data.Data1
    INNER JOIN
        (Data.trans_UN, Data.input_Ex, Data.trans_M, Data.trans_Pa) ON (Data.trans_Une.Une_ID = Data.input_Data1.Une_ID
        AND Data.trans_Une.GN = Data.input_Ex.GN
        AND Data.input_Ex.EQ = Data.trans_M.EQ
        AND Data.input_Ex.GL = Data.trans_M.GL
        AND Data.input_Ex.MN = Data.trans_P.GP)
    WHERE
        Data.tGModel = 'Model1'
    GROUP BY Data.Data1.`Year` , Data.Data1.`Month`
```

PHP Code:

```
    $time_mysql_data = -microtime(true);    
    $sth1 = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        sum((1 - (Data.Data1.`Ggdata` / 100)) * (Data.Data1.`Datagg`)) As 'EUH'
    FROM
        Data.Data1
    INNER JOIN
        (Data.trans_UN, Data.input_Ex, Data.trans_M, Data.trans_Pa) ON (Data.trans_Une.Une_ID = Data.input_Data1.Une_ID
        AND Data.trans_Une.GN = Data.input_Ex.GN
        AND Data.input_Ex.EQ = Data.trans_M.EQ
        AND Data.input_Ex.GL = Data.trans_M.GL
        AND Data.input_Ex.MN = Data.trans_P.GP)
    WHERE
        Data.tGModel = 'Model1'
    GROUP BY Data.Data1.`Year` , Data.Data1.`Month`");
    $time_mysql_data += microtime(true);

    $time_php_data = -microtime(true);
    $rows1 = array();
    $rows1['name'] = 'EUH';
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth1)) {
        $rows1['data'][] = $r['EUH'];
    };
    $time_php_data += microtime(true);
```

I know I should use mysqli or PDO, and I am doing it. This code is just not renewed yet :)

Thnks

Comment: so you mean it suppose to execute so long? or I should do something with query cache, like enlarge it..?

Comment: It could execute that long, depends on the db/tables schema and indexes. Not properly indexed tables can make you bad time while joining. You can play with the cache to see if decreases the execution, and how long it takes after executing second time on the same session.

Comment: but why so big difference in Workbench?

Comment: It's already cached there

Comment: Is workbench silently appending a LIMIT clause to the query? And so perhaps only loading say the first 100 rows. If you scroll down, it issues another query?

Comment: Also it could depends on the connection. As maybe via the tool, you are already connected to the database, but via PHP each time you select DataBaseName.TableName.ColumnName, you make request to the db

Comment: OK, after 2 execution it took less then a second. So I think I have to read more about db/tables schema and indexes.

Comment: @barryhunter Workbench doesn't append LIMIT, it gives me exactly 48 rows, as it should does.

Comment: You need to properly index your tables, and, if your set of queries involves one database, to drop the using of the db name in the query, and connect to this database before start querying.

Comment: Just guessing - but how do you connect to the db? sockets/tcp? And is it local or remote? Maybe you have a large overhead on the connection and not on the query itself?

Comment: I connect to the db at the beginning of PHP and close the connection at the end. So the question is how to properly index my tables..

Comment: @sebapalus Database is on a remote server. But how do I connect with it? I don't know :) I simply use mysqli_connect.

Comment: How to properly index your tables is something you have to find by yourself even more if you are the one who designed them.

Comment: That is the problem... I have not design them :)